# how to use provider for redux to connect it with map state

Tags: react-native

i have build an full stack drawer and tab navigators in my app.js and now how can i use provider of redux to connect in whole app should i create an new screen and move all components of app.js to that or do something in app.js

```
const SplashScreen = createStackNavigator({
ScreenWith:{
  screen:ScreenWith,
  navigationOptions:{
    headerTitle:'Logo1',
  },
},
});

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Homeview: {
    screen: Homeview,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: 'Home',
    },
  },
  Beauty: {
    screen: Beauty,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: 'Beauty',
     },
    },
    ContentPage:{
      screen:ContentPage,
      navigationOptions:{
        headerTitle:'Authenticated',
      },
    },


     Yourcart:{
      screen:Yourcart,
      navigationOptions:{
        headerTitle:'Your Cart',
      },
     },
       SignIn: {
    screen: SignIn,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: 'SignIn',
     },
    },
    Signup:{
      screen:Signup,
      navigationOptions:{
        headerTitle:'Registered',
      },
    },
    Forgotemail:{
      screen:Forgotemail,
      navigationOptions:{
        headerTitle:'Forgotemail',
      }
    },   
});


const MainTabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeStack,

  },
  Account: {
    screen: Account,

  },



  },
});


const MainDrawer = createDrawerNavigator({
   MainTabs : MainTabs,
   },{
  contentComponent:props =><Drawescreen {...props}/>
});


const AppModalStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    App: MainDrawer,
    Screentest: Homeview,

  },
  {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);

const App = createSwitchNavigator({

  SplashScreen: {
    screen: SplashScreen,
  },
  App: {
    screen: AppModalStack,
  },
});

export default createAppContainer(App);
```

this is my app.js now where i should i add provider to connect with redux ?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have export your Container as **App**

Assume that you have created a class called **Main** for import your Container App file

This is how you add Provider to your app:

```
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App'; //Import your app Container
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'; //Import Provider
import store from '../redux/store/store'; //Import your store

const reduxStore = store(); //create redux store

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={reduxStore}>
          <AppContainer />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: import your store from your project. Have you created your redux store ?